# Proware SB-2124-G1A3 password reset

Tags: raid, iscsi, password-reset

We have been using the Proware SB-2124-G1A3 device for more than 10 years. But now we have discovered that the administrator password is irretrievably lost. The official documentation describes password reset procedures that work only with knowledge of the previous one. If you are familiar with this device (i hope there is couple of guys and gals who is) please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use web interface for management did you check the passwords stored in the browsers?

Comment: Also did you try with default password **00000000**?

Comment: 00000000 is not work, we have tried it...

Comment: and we don't save management password in browsers for security reasons :-(

Comment: Have you try to "Reset to Default" via front panel? according to documentation this will set the password to zeroes and set IP to specific value page 24/25, https://www.proware.com.tw/product/manual_pdf/sb-2124-g1s3_v1.2.pdf

Comment: We tried this... LCD front panel interface also requests for password.

Comment: In such case I will recommend to open a request to the manufacturer (can cost you good amount of money because this system is defined as legacy product)